# Unity Facebook login not works on Facebook App in the Android device

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine, authentication

So i implemented Facebook SDK in my project, here the problem is FBlogin not works when i have facebook app in my android device. Please my and my team stuck in this stuff. For more details please replay to this post.

Here is the Code of my Facebook. It is working great when i uninstall facebook app in my device.

With facebook app in my android device : When open my game, facebook window is appear like do you want to continue insted of Login ask, when i click continue its not fetching my details like "Name and Profile Pic"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Facebook.Unity;
using Facebook.MiniJSON;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string fbname;
    public string get_data;
    public InputField login_name;
    public Image profilePic;
    public Text fbNameText,FriendsText;//BABJI
    public GameObject loginPanel,mainPanel;

    public bool loggedIn;
    void Awake ()
    {
        if (!FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            FB.Init(() =>
                {
                    if (FB.IsInitialized)
                        FB.ActivateApp();
                    else
                        Debug.LogError("Couldn't initialize");
                },
                isGameShown =>
                {
                    if (!isGameShown)
                        Time.timeScale = 0;
                    else
                        Time.timeScale = 1;
                });
        }
        else
            FB.ActivateApp();

    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (GameSaver.instance.isFBLogin) {
            loginPanel.SetActive (false);
            login_name.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            mainPanel.SetActive (true);
//          StartCoroutine (DelayLogIn ());
        } else {
            loginPanel.SetActive (true);
        }
    }

//  IEnumerator DelayLogIn()
//  {
//      yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
//
//  }
    private void InitCallback ()
    {
        if (FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp();
            // Continue with Facebook SDK
            // ...
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
        }
    }
    private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) {
            // Pause the game - we will need to hide
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else {
            // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    public void LoginCalled()
    {

        if (!FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            var perms = new List<string> (){ "public_profile", "email" };
            FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (perms, AuthCallback);
        }
        else 
        {
            //

        }
        // you are already logged in, do something
        FB.API("me?fields=name", HttpMethod.GET, GetFacebookData);
        FB.API("me/picture?type=square&height=128&width=128", HttpMethod.GET, GetProfilePicture);
        login_name.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        mainPanel.SetActive (true);
        loginPanel.SetActive (false);
        GameSaver.instance.isFBLogin=true;
        GameSaver.instance.SaveGameData ();
    }

    private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) 
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) 
            {
                Debug.Log(perm);
            }
            FB.API("me?fields=name", Facebook.Unity.HttpMethod.GET, GetFacebookData);
            //FB.API("/me/picture?redirect=false", HttpMethod.GET, GetProfilePicture);
            //BABJI
            FB.API("me/picture?type=square&height=128&width=128", HttpMethod.GET, GetProfilePicture);
            login_name.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            mainPanel.SetActive (true);
            loginPanel.SetActive (false);
            GameSaver.instance.isFBLogin=true;
            GameSaver.instance.SaveGameData ();
            //BABJI
            loggedIn = FB.IsLoggedIn;
        } 
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
        }
    }

    void GetFacebookData(IResult result)
    {
        fbname = result.ResultDictionary["name"].ToString ();
        login_name.text = fbname ;
        login_name.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        fbNameText.text = fbname;
        Debug.Log("fbName: " + fbname);

    }

    private void GetProfilePicture(IGraphResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error == null && result.Texture != null)
        {       
            profilePic.sprite = Sprite.Create (result.Texture, new Rect (0, 0, 128, 128), new Vector2 ());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Here i added my code. Please is this sdk issue or am doing any wrong.

Comment: make sure that your unity app HASH matches the one u link to your facebook bundleid

Comment: Ya got it. Problem solved. I put my hash key in developer Facebook page, what my mobile gives to me, then it's working. But some problem is there. When I First open the game it ask for login or continue that's great, when I close the app and again open my game it's not initialize the Facebook data. Please check my code is am doing any wrong.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what we have discussed above 
try this code :

```
public void Awake()
{
        // Init Facebook SDK
        if (!FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            // Initialize the Facebook SDK Configuration
            FB.Init(InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
        }
        else
        {
             // Already initialized, signal an app activation App Event
             FB.ActivateApp();
        }
}

private void InitCallback() {
        if (FB.IsInitialized)
        {
            // Signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
        }
} 
private void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
{
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            // Here is the region where u r loggged in from facebook acccount
            // Just put your Logic Here
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Facebook User cancelled login");
        }
}
```

and here is what you need to call when u press a button,

```
public void LoginWithFaceBook()
{
        var perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email" };
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}
```

also use this when u logout from your application

```
public void FacebookLogout()
{
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            FB.LogOut();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks am trying, and let u know.

Comment: My game is not stay in login when I close and open again my game. I have to click again(2nd time) login button to fetch my data like "name and profile pic"